# UiPath cannot click Chrome Browser popup dialogs

Tags: google-chrome, uipath, uipath-studio

I am having a lot of trouble with a few small parts in a couple of automation workflows and would really appreciate any help. We use UiPath for tons of stuff dealing with our ERP, Great Plains, using the GP Web Client in Chrome, but I have been stuck trying to simply reload the browser. It seems that there is no way that I can find to interact with any Chrome dialog boxes, like Reload or Print dialog prompts like this example:

[image]

I have tried using both Element click selectors and Image selectors with timeouts and such but cannot interact with these Chrome dialogs in any way. I also tried sending hotkeys to just click enter like I can without UiPath, but nothing in UiPath will even recognize the prompt. It even ignores these Chrome dialogs when using the record activities. I have the correct Chrome extension and everything else works, but dialogs seem impossible to deal with.

Here are two examples of selectors that I have tried:

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of in Studio and scoured the Forums, but have found nothing helpful. Does anyone have any tricks for working with Chrome dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is something where UiPath does not offer a proper solution. I also had several ideas about that. But just one was working reliable.

It's very simple. You just **set the Enter key** on the browser:

[image: activities]

and the **properties** should like these:

[image: properties]

If you need the Close in your case clicked. You use an additional Tab hotkey at the beginning.

Also you do not have to use the **Attach Window** activity. This is optional. You can just use the **Send Hotkey**.

Comment: Wow, excellent, this did the trick right away, thanks so much! I played with similar settings, but it looks like adding that lower 3000 ms timeout and Waitforready.Complete did the trick. Very useful work-around!

Comment: is this approach is browser safe? What I mean is can this work for all browser? I want my application to be browser independent and hence asking this question

Comment: I am just using Chrome at the moment. But yes should work in any browser. It just hits the enter key. And this works in any browser that shows that dialog.